What is the difference between using a resistor or a capacitor as current limiter?
Sorry if my question is too basic but I really can't get the idea here. I have this circuit here in which 220 VAC is connected to an optocoupler via these two 120 K resistors results 240 K.
What is the difference between using these resistors or just a capacitor and depends on its impedance to limit the current? I am aware of the phase shifting that the capacitor causes.


The resistor will shed heat - a lot of it, especially when compared to the power consumed in the LED. The capacitor won't since it is a reactive element. So it's kind of a no-brainer: use a capacitor.
How? Set the capacitance value to have an impedance equivalent to what you'd need for a dropping resistor.
For example, for 240V/50Hz and an RMS current of 10mA (why? See below), you need a dropping value of about 24k ohms. For 50Hz, a capacitor that gives that impedance is about 0.13uF. Since that isn't a common value, use 0.1uF (Z = 26k @50Hz) instead which would be close enough. Add a series resistor too - 470 ohms or so.
Simulate it here

All the real power is dissipated in the LEDs and small series resistor; none in the capacitor.
Tips:

Check the coupler's current transfer ratio. Datasheet shows a range of 20 - 300%, so you likely need more than 1mA drive as you show. That's why I chose 10mA for my example.
Use an appropriate safety-rated cap (600V or more). A Y capacitor would be a good choice as it is designed to fail 'open'.
Enclose the entire line-voltage side to prevent shock.
Don't assume line and neutral won't be swapped - treat the neutral connection as if it were live.

MORE: As a way to better illustrate the wasteful power loss, here's a sim that shows the power consumed by each approach (simulate it here):

In this sim we can see that when we select the resistor approach we  dissipate over 1.8W average while delivering only 12mW to the LEDs, for peak current of 10mA. That's wasteful and unnecessary. Even if we reduce the peak to just 1mA (increase resistor to 310k), we're still wasting 180+ mW in the resistor.
Flip the switch back to the cap approach and you can see the power drop down to just 38mW average. About half is shed in the 470 ohm, which isn't strictly necessary but is there to protect against transients.

but the resistor do have relatively low heat  dissipated even with higher AC voltage.
peak power is 311:  so they will roughly dissipate 200 mW , so I already used 1 W rated resistor, isn't that enough for it? or still the capacitor better?

200mW heat overhead is a lot for an LED that’s dissipating only tens of mW. And, you will likely need to increase the current, making matters worse.

You should be able to use a cap instead of resistors. If you have any other inductance, they could lower the voltage. I even simulated a spike and it did not increase the current substantially. Allthough the caps have a higher voltage on spikes in AC mains that might come through. One problem with a cap is creep-age and clearance, so that would eliminate many SMT caps.
Intuition says resistors would be better.


You can use a capacitor with some series resistance to limit the current if switched at AC peak or if a massive transient comes along, but the circuit you have  works reliably and you have adequate voltage rating on the resistors for AC transients to meet standards, I would stick with it.
Power dissipation is around 1/4-W, not much, and it is simple, compact should be reliable and it is as good as dealing with transients as you can get without adding additional parts.
You can inexpensively and safely reduce the power dissipation to half again (to 0.125W) by adding a 1N4007/M7 in series, but I would keep the AC-input opto (or use a parallel diode) since the effect of reverse leakage may be to damage the LED over time. You will get one pulse per cycle rather than two that way.
If you have a 1kV transient with 0.5usec rise time, the current passed through a 0.1uF capacitor would be a couple hundred A without the resistor, so chances are the resistor will fail (1kΩ would be dissipating 1kW), even if it is a special surge-resistant film resistor (some other types will survive).

I am thinking of using a bi directional TVS diode too rated at 5 V as for protection of surges too. it is not stated here in the datasheet but the reverse voltage normally should be 6 V, so would I be safe from reverse leakage current of the LED? Unfortunately speed is needed so I can't make it as just 1 pulse, and I am thinking of using two different Mono optocouplers but that would be more expensive.

Capacitors also behave impressively bad when fed off a square-wave inverter or an arcing power plug, for similar reasons.

How to reduce voltage
Generally speaking, the idea behind analog transformerless methods of voltage reduction is to remove a part of the input voltage.
By resistance
We can do it by connecting a resistor between the voltage source and load. A voltage drop occurs across the resistor, which is subtracted from the input voltage, thus reducing it.
By opposing voltage
But we can do it directly by connecting an opposing voltage source instead. Its voltage (acting as a drop) is subtracted from the input voltage, thus reducing it.
Implementation
If the input voltage source is AC (sinusoidal), then the opposing source is also AC and their difference appears across the load as a sine AC voltage. In such a capacitive dropper, a capacitor functions as the counteracting voltage source.
In the circuits below, I have grounded the input voltage source and capacitor (so we can easily compare their voltages) and left the load "floating". Grounding is also necessary for the simulator.
Exploring the operation
Time-Domain Simulation
Let's first explore the circuit through time...

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
... and measure the voltages at four key time points - at 6th, 11th, 16th and 21st ms.

DC Simulation
Then, for each of these points, let's replace the input AC source and the capacitor with constant DC voltage sources with the corresponding instantaneous voltage. For purposes of intuitive understanding, let's set their polarity by their orientation, not by their voltage sign (i.e., to flip the symbol during the negative half wave). Also, we can represent the load by a real voltmeter with 1 kΩ internal resistance.
Green arrows show the current direction; red arrows show how voltages change.
You can think of the four conceptual schematics below as four snapshots of the schematic taken at key points.
6th ms (Vin > Vc) Initially, Vin exceeds Vc, and both voltages change in a positive direction.

simulate this circuit
11th ms (Vin = Vc) Somewhere after the positive peak of the sine wave they become equal...

simulate this circuit
16th ms (Vin < Vc) ... and begin to decrease as now Vc remains higher than Vin.

simulate this circuit
21st ms (Vin = Vc) Somewhere before the negative peak of the sine wave they become equal again...

simulate this circuit

The advantage of the capacitor is that current and voltage in the capacitor are 90 degrees out of phase. That means that in steady state AC conditions there is no net transfer of energy from the grid to the capacitor.
However a capacitor has a couple of downsides.

It's impedance is frequency dependent. If someone plugs your device into a 400Hz socket on an aircraft you have just increased the current by a factor of 8.
Immediately after switch-on the capacitor is essentially a short-circuit.
After switch-off hazardous voltage may remain on the capacitor if there is not a suitable discharge path.

These problems can be mitigated, but that means additional components increasing overall complexity.
